# How Bind a property to ApplicationRessource located in App.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding

I created a CParametres object in my **app.xaml.cs** like this :

```
public partial class App : Application
{
   public CParametres myParamObject;

   protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
   {
       base.OnStartup(e);
       myParamObject    =   new CParametres(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName) +@"\BingMapsParam.ini");
       if (myParamObject.LoadParams() == false)
       {
           return;   
       }
       Resources.Add("myParamObject", myParamObject);
   }

}
```

**Now, in my app.xaml, i add a Dictionnary :**

```
<Application x:Class="myGeoloc.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>

    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="MyDictionary.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>

</Application.Resources>
```

**And, here is my Dictionnary :**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:t="clr-namespace:myGeoloc"
                xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF">
<t:CParametres x:Key="myParamObject"/>
<Style TargetType="m:Pushpin" x:Key="PushpinStyle_Fournisseur">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="m:Pushpin" >
                <!--   <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="C:\Users\FabioWalter\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\myGeoloc\myGeoloc\bin\Debug\Pushpins\PushPinStandard.png" />-->
                <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding Path=strPicturePushpinFournisseur, Source={StaticResource myParamObject}}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="64" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="64" />
</Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

strPicturePushpinFournisseur is string in CParametres. This string contain the picture paths.

Actually, the image don't display and it's related to my bad binding.

Anyone could help me please ?
Any ideas ?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do some thing like this:

*To put the object in the resource dictionary for making it available to the rest of the application*

```
    <Application x:Class="SomeNameSpace.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:t="clr-namespace:SomeNameSpace.NameSpaceForT"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="View/DictionaryResources/MainResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <t:CParametres x:Key="myParamObject"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </Application.Resources>
    </Application>
```

*Make a binding to any object's property (This is a sample):*

```
<Window x:Class="SomeNameSpace.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:View="clr-namespace:SomeNameSpace.View"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    DataContext="{Binding Path=strPicturePushpinFournisseur, Source={StaticResource myParamObject}}"
    Height="350" Width="525">
...
```

---

**EDIT**

---

You can create the object in the `App.xaml.cs` file, and add contructor parameters in this way:

```
public partial class App : Application
{


    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        Resources.Add("myParamObject", new CParametres ("Param1", "Param2"));
    }
}
```

And use it in this way:

```
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=strPicturePushpinFournisseur, Source={StaticResource myParamObject}}"></TextBlock>
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks, and, how define the 't:' for the CParametres object

Comment: Yes i saw :) . Now i cannot add the  <ResourceDictionary>. it appear to be forbidden. "The Resources property can be defined only one time."

Comment: Yes, you only need to add the `<t:CParametres x:Key="myParamObject"/>` line to your old dictionary resource, or you can have merged dictionaries resources -> See Update, in that way you can add other resource dictionaries

Comment: Why merging ? I actually have 0 dictionaries resource, i juste use the Application Ressource located in the App.xaml. In addition, why steeing the dataContext in the MainWindows. I need to set in the App.xaml.cs no ?

Comment: The DataContext in the Main WIndows is only a binding sample, you don't have to do it. Also you can to create an instace in the App.xaml file (like in this answer), it is the right way. In the way you was working you are not putting it in the dictionary.

Comment: It is not needed (MVVM), in this case.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer, but i don't understand why merging dictionnaries, i have 0 dictionnary and i cannot create it like in your example :(

Comment: Yes, it is possible, please post your `app.xaml` code in the question, for show you...

Comment: I progressed...I created my dictionnary....Now, my probleme is thaht the compiler tell me : "CParametres don't contain accessible constructor". Nevertheless, my CParametres constructor and class are public !

Comment: The constructor should have not parameters. If the constructor have some params, then you only can add to the resource dictionary from the code behind. I will try some code (for testing it), and then update the answer.

Comment: I added in my class an empty constructor. My binding appear to be empty too....But i don't want to instanciate an empty CParameters object. I want to bing propery of my CparameterObject which is already instancied in my App.xaml.cs ( the object is name my myParamObject).

Comment: I edited my code, see my actual code in my first post :) Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, nevertheless, binding appear to be not valid :( Picture don't display. If i setted "source" directly with my png, it's ok. I updated my code now on the first post.

Comment: Try put the image directly on the MainWindow, and not inside a style.

Comment: I cannot...it's for personnalize the picture of a Pushpin (bing maps pushpin), and the only solution is to use a style :\

Comment: OK, i'm actually trying ;)

Comment: Yeh, it appear to be ok :) Thanks a lot for all your help my friend :)

Comment: Walter, if finally this answer works for you, you should mark it as aceppted!